# Canonical Link HTTP Response Header being stripped using PHP / Apache

Tags: php, apache, http, header, canonical-link

I am trying to output a HTTP header using PHP that specifies a canonical url as per Google's guidelines : [Specify a canonical link in your HTTP header](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#6) in the following format:

```
Link: <http://www.example.com/downloads/white-paper.pdf>; rel="canonical"
```

However the response header is being stripped with result being

```
Link: ; rel="canonical"
```

As a test, I removed the left/right angle brackets, and the result is:

```
Link: http://www.example.com/downloads/white-paper.pdf; rel="canonical"
```

Which makes me think some security measure (PHP/Apache/Apache module??) is seeing the header content as HTML and 'helping' by stripping it out.

The reason the canonical needs to be specified in the headers and not simply in the <head> is that the document is a PDF.

This is some test code to illustrate what I am doing:

```
<?php
header("link: <https://www.somedomain.com/>; rel=\"canonical\"");
print "this is a test";?>
```

The list of modules loaded in apache is:

> core_module (static)
>    log_config_module (static)
>    logio_module (static)
>    version_module (static)
>    mpm_prefork_module (static)
>    http_module (static)
>    so_module (static)
>    alias_module (shared)
>    auth_basic_module (shared)
>    authn_file_module (shared)
>    authz_default_module (shared)
>    authz_groupfile_module (shared)
>    authz_host_module (shared)
>    authz_user_module (shared)
>    cgi_module (shared)
>    deflate_module (shared)
>    dir_module (shared)
>    env_module (shared)
>    expires_module (shared)
>    mime_module (shared)
>    negotiation_module (shared)
>    pagespeed_module (shared)
>    php5_module (shared)
>    reqtimeout_module (shared)
>    rewrite_module (shared)
>    setenvif_module (shared)
>    ssl_module (shared)
>    status_module (shared)

Note that suhosin is not loaded, so that can be ruled out.. 
Any help identifying what could be modifying the header appreciated.

Update: I have tried this on a few different servers, and the result is the same so far.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that the tools I was using to inspect the headers was inferior (probably not escaping the headers correctly before showing them as HTML):

Specifically Chrome extension "CDN Headers & Cookies" and some online checker I can no longer find.

Chrome's default F12 header inspector shows the responses headers correctly though, apologies if I wasted anyone's time.